# .htaccess mod-rewrite urls ending with "-XXXX" (dash, numbers)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to match on urls that end with a dash and a set of numbers (or just one number) but doesnt work:

Example:  domain.com/my-product-36-inches-long-135355

```
# rewrite urls
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# product 
RewriteRule ^shop/-([0-9,]+)/?$ product.php?url_key=$1 [NC,L]

# category
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/.]+)$ category.php?url_key=$1 [NC,L]

# sub category
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ subcategory.php?url_key=$1&url_key2=$2 [NC,L]

# list (from subcategory page; will have 3 variables)
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ list.php?mr=3&url_key1=$1&url_key2=$2&url_key3=$3 [NC,L]

# list (from category page; will have 4 variables)
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ list.php?mr=4&url_key1=$1&url_key2=$2&url_key3=$3&url_key4=$4 [NC,L]



# business types
RewriteRule ^shop/restaurant-supply-business-type section.php?id=1 [NC,L]

# login
RewriteRule ^shop/customer/account/login login.php [NC,L]

# brands
RewriteRule ^shop/shopby/brand brands.php [NC,L]

# professional services
RewriteRule ^shop/professional-services professional_services.php [NC,L]

# pages 
RewriteRule ^locations/([^/.]+)$  page.php?url_key=locations/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^locations page.php?url_key=locations [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^testimonials page.php?url_key=testimonials [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us page.php?url_key=contact-us [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^equipment-checklist page.php?url_key=equipment-checklist [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^shipping page.php?url_key=shipping [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^returns page.php?url_key=returns [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^lease-financing page.php?url_key=lease-financing [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news page.php?url_key=news [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^advice page.php?url_key=advice [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us page.php?url_key=about-us [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^careers page.php?url_key=careers [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy page.php?url_key=privacy [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms-of-use page.php?url_key=terms-of-use [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)$ page.php?url_key=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^section/([^/.]+)$ section.php?url_key=$1 [NC,L]


# Remove all .php extensions without interfering with .js or .css.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Remove index from url.
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match just the ending part using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/.*-([0-9,]+)/?$ product.php?url_key=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I couldn't get it to work.  Same 404 I get. Here is a real url example of doesn't work: /shop/fountain-jar-2-qt-22916

Comment: Updated it to show all.  I do not have a shop directory, it is all in the root.  My problem is category, subcategory, list and product all must use /shop/.

Comment: Tried it, same thing.  I has something to do with it matching the same thing as the #category I believe.  I can get #product to work with this:
`RewriteRule ^shop/product/([^/.]+)$ product.php?url_key=$1 [NC,L]` but I need it to only be at "/shop/" without the /product/ in the url.

Comment: I believe for `/shop/fountain-jar-2-qt-22916` you want actual internal URI to be `product.php?url_key=22916` ? Does `example.com/product.php?url_key=22916` work fine?

Comment: Yes but not in the way you have shown.  It is the url_key, so `example.com/product.php?url_key=the-key-assigned-to-a-sku-in-db-22916` does work correctly.

Comment: But this rule is only rewriting it to `example.com/product.php?url_key=22916` could this be problem?

Comment: I think you are correct, I probably need to re-write the code on that page to `_GET` from the `SKU` instead of the `url_key`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the end of uri that contains (-numbers or numbers) only use the following  :

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)(-([0-9]+)|([0-9]+))$  product.php?url_key=$2 [R,L,NE]
```

If (-numbers or only one digit of numbers) use the following  :

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)(-([0-9]+)|\b[0-9]\b)$ product.php?url_key=$2 [R,L,NE]
```